# Is there a javascript library that has the ability to modify and save images?

Tags: javascript, image, save, draw, shapes

Is there a javascript library that has the ability to modify and save images? It would preferably be able to draw primitives and then save the image at the very  least.

Comment: This can be done with Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these:

- [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com)
- [canvas2image](https://github.com/hongru/canvas2image)